# Adaptable Alternating Least Squares Method

Tags: recommender-system

I am building a recommendater system using Collaborative Filtering. I have implemented Alternating Least Square method following [this tutorial](https://bugra.github.io/work/notes/2014-04-19/alternating-least-squares-method-for-collaborative-filtering/). Now I want my algorithm to adapt new ratings for movies that were previously not rated. Should the algorithm run again with same number of iterations to adapt new ratings. Or number of iterations can be reduced. Or is there any other method of adapting new ratings.

### EDIT:

Even running one iteration of ALS takes significant time. Hence adapting new changes by running it again is not a solution.

Comment: I do not know what a recommendater system is and also what collaborating filtering is.  You probably need additional tags that the members of this site will recognize. I think a self-study tag would be one of them.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, collaborative filtering is a machine learning method.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the first answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109202/updating-svd-in-recommender-systems-for-change-in-ratings) and the method it proposes. One round of ALS to factor in the new rating(s) works well in practice (See [Fig 5 in this paper for a result on that](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bc43/1f385822efc00541b896cc83a0972e478e01.pdf)).

In fact, you can get away with just running a stochastic gradient descent update for only the specific user and item vector for which you received a new rating.

Comment: thanx but i found a solution some time ago. [here](https://stanford.edu/~rezab/classes/cme323/S15/notes/lec14.pdf) is the link i used to solve this issue.